# Running WebDAV server, but cannot publish from Thunderbird

Tags: sync, thunderbird, calendar, webdav, caldav

I installed and have a running WebDAV server (Davical) and now would like to publish my calendar from Thunderbird (Lightning), as advertised here: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/exporting-and-sharing-a-calendar (under "Steps when Running Lightning").

However, I don't know my WebDAV URL. Quite probably I don't really understand how it is supposed to work. Do I have to create a new calendar on the server first? Or how is publishing meant to work?

In the end, I'd like to have a regularly synced iCal URL on my WebDAV server, so I can access it through Google Calendar (as Google Calendar apparently does not work with CalDAV).

**EDIT**: I created a principal `myusername` with all rights in the Davical admin panel and tried to publish an *existing* calendar (which is my particular use case – I don't want to create a *new* calendar on the server) under the following url: `http://myurl.com/caldav.php/myusername/calendar` and what I get from Thunderbird is:

```
Publishing the calendar file failed.
Status code: 405: Method Not Allowed
```

**EDIT 2**: I was actually able to publish the calendar by using the following URL: `http://myurl.com/caldav.php/myusername/calendar/test.ics`, so that problem is solved by appending `test.ics` or any other filename to the above URL. Now, I can subscribe to it from Google Calendar, but unfortunately, the events are not displayed there... Maybe it is because of permissions? Google Calendar does not have a field where I can enter credentials.

Comment: Have you tried following the official guide: https://www.davical.org/clients.php?client=Thunderbird ?

Comment: Sure, but this is for creating a *new* calendar on the server. I, however, would like to publish an existing calender to WebDAV, so that I can pull it into Google Cal.

Comment: Try [Sync Calendar with Mozilla Lightning](https://www.webdavsystem.com/server/access/caldav/mozilla_lightning/).

Comment: Yes. Doesn't add any information, see original question.

Answer (score 0):

The following is paraphrased from DAViCal's [General Client Configuration Information](https://www.davical.org/clients.php):

> Thunderbird wants a 'calendar' URL which is something like:
>
> `http://calendar.example.net/caldav.php/username/calendar/`
>
> The host name is up to you. The 'root path' should be `/caldav.php/` and
> anything following that is the calendar namespace.
>
> Within the calendar namespace DAViCal uses the first element of the
> path as the user or 'princpal' name, so that a client connecting at
> the root path can see all of the (accessible) users and resources
> available to them with any calendars below that.

Once you have your URL, DAViCal provides the [Thunderbird-specific illustrated setup info](https://www.davical.org/clients.php?client=Thunderbird) noted in the comment by @dirdi.

Comment: Okay, I did exactly that (although I think the setup info is for creating a *new* calendar, not publishing an existing one, and I'm only talking about this - why should there a button in the Thunderbird context menu if that is not a use case?). However, upon publishing in Thunderbird, I get: "Publishing the calendar file failed.
Status code: 405: Method Not Allowed". I edited my answer to reflect this.